# Rails Finding the storing file local URL in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, ocr, carrierwave

Working on a project that use a gem named OcrSpace to perform ocr on image uploaded by carrierwave .

After a button is clicked, the text in the image would be shown in the website.

Here's the code:

```
<%= image_tag( @resume.attachment_url) %>
<div id="cool"> </div>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<% require 'ocr_space' resource = OcrSpace::Resource.new(apikey: "xxxxxxxxx") %>

<% result = resource.clean_convert file: @resume.attachment_url %>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cool").innerHTML = <%= result %>;
}
</script>
```

However, I got this error

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /uploads/resume/attachment/3/_____2018-07-19___9.15.42.jpg

It seems that the file path is incorrect

Can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

> @resume.attachment.path

instead of @resume.attachment_url

url will not give you a local path to open as a file

Comment: I changed it. But it is now showing a new error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: can you send me which line of code raised this error?

Comment: this line: <% result = resource.clean_convert file: resume.attachment.path
 %>

Comment: might be the problem of the api ocr_space: https://github.com/suyesh/ocr_space     I change @resume.attachment.path to a path like the example on this gem’s github /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/nicola_tesla.jpg

. But it still return the same error